# Threading Mechanism for the following Scenario

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to multithreading programming.

Is it possible to have the following situation?

If one thread is writing on a object, no other threads can read or write on it.

If on one is writing on it, every one can read the object at the same time?

C# explanation is prefered.

Answer (score 7):

Sure, what you're looking for is a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` (or `ReaderWriterLock` on older versions of .NET).  There's a specific class just for that in `System.Threading`.  When you're writing you take out a write lock, when you're reading you take out a read lock.  It then exhibits the behavior you've described.

Comment: Thank you and user2418842,

I didn't state my question clearly.

I want the "lock" to lock on a key object like the keyword "lock" does. I did check out the documentation on ReadWriteLock. It can create a critical section on a piece of code. But it doesn't have a lock key.

Comment: The 'lock' keyword has no capabilities to differentiate between a read lock and a write lock.  You'll have to do without it.

Comment: @user2418842 It *is* the lock key.  If you were to try to use the C# `lock` keyword then how would you know if you were in a write block or a read block?  In any case, the `lock` keyword is just syntactic sugar for taking a lock and releasing it in a finally; you simply need to write that out.  `try{myReadWriteLock.EnterReadLock(); SomeCode();}finally{myReadWriteLock.ExitReadLock();}`

Comment: An alternative is to create 2 helper classes `ReadLock` and `WriteLock`, both implementing the `IDispoable` interface, then you can use 'using' instead of 'lock'.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `ReaderWriterLock` object. It allows you to acquire a read lock or a write lock as well as ability to escalate a read lock to a write lock so that you can check first then write. [This MSDN article explains it all.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx)